# Bank Card code breaking probability problem.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume that $10.000$ bank cards have been stolen by different thieves during a year. For every bank card the thieves try to break the code. The thieves don't exchange any information about what codes they have tried to break the code of their card. What is the possibility the the code is cracked for 3 or more bank cards. Assume also that the possibility for cracking a code is $0.0003$.

$P(X>=3) = 1- P(X<3)$ is what I started with but something feels wrong because this way the probability is absurd (too high).

$P(X>=3) = 1- P(X<3)= 1-0.0003*3=0.991$

Comment: What did you get as probability?

Comment: @Hetebrij I got 0.9991. Correct answer is 0.5768

Comment: That is indeed absurd high. Could you perhaps write your steps, so it possible to pinpoint where you went wrong?

Comment: @Hetebrij I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) is what you need.

Having posed $n=10'000$ and $p=0.0001$
$$P(X\geq 3) = 1- P(X<3) = 1 - (P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2) = \\
= 1- {n \choose 0}p^0(1-p)^n-{n \choose 1}p^1(1-p)^{n-1} - {n \choose 2}p^2(1-p)^{n-2} \simeq 0.0803  $$

If $p=0.0003$, then the solution in $0.5768$.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't really understood binomial distribution but I will have another go at it. Thanks again for pointing it out to me :)